# Create a for-loop to read big data in chunks and create new columns

Tags: r, loops, bigdata

I am new to programming with R.

I am trying to write a loop in which reads chuck of data separately (as the size of data is 20GB with 300 million rows) and performs a code to create columns for dates and write it out each chunk as a csv file in each folder. The following is a trial which was suggested by another member. It works smoothly but the only problem is that I am not able to write each chunk in the same loop once it performs the process.

```
index = 0
nrows = length(count.fields("RM.csv", sep = ",")) 
df = vector('list',ceiling(nrows/2)) 
col_names = colnames(read.csv('RM.csv', nrow=1, header = T))
end_found=FALSE

while(!end_found)
{
  begin = 1000*index
  end = min(nrows,begin+1000)
  print(paste0("Reading rows ", begin+1 ," to ", end ))
  df[[index+1]] = fread('RM.csv',skip = begin, nrows =end-begin,
                        col.names = col_names)
  index = index+1
  if(end==nrows) end_found=TRUE
  df = do.call(as.data.frame,df)
  write.csv(df,file = paste0('test1',index,'.csv'))
}
```

Data:

```
RM.csv:
        Date
    1   7/30/2017 19:16
    2   7/30/2017 19:05
    3   7/30/2017 19:03
    4   7/30/2017 19:37
    5   7/30/2017 18:36
    6   7/30/2017 20:08
    7   7/30/2017 19:00
    8   7/30/2017 19:21
    9   7/30/2017 17:01
```

Desired Output:

```
    Date    Month   Year
1   7/30/2017 19:16 Jul-17  2017
2   7/30/2017 19:05 Jul-17  2017
3   7/30/2017 19:03 Jul-17  2017
4   7/30/2017 19:37 Jul-17  2017
5   7/30/2017 18:36 Jul-17  2017
6   7/30/2017 20:08 Jul-17  2017
7   7/30/2017 19:00 Jul-17  2017
8   7/30/2017 19:21 Jul-17  2017
9   7/30/2017 17:01 Jul-17  2017
```

Comment: Can you describe what the expected output is? It's a bit hard to visualise without knowing what the `RM.csv` look like. Also, it's a bad idea to loop and read a big input file repeatedly.

Comment: Are you aware that you can append data to files. Read the help page for `write.table`.

Comment: @Adam Quek I have updated my question. So say I extract a chunk of 9 rows with Date using this loop than I two more columns such as Month and Year to be created for that same chunk and it should write out a csv file in the same directory. Later on using a batch script or MySQL I will append this files.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to  break `iris` data set into 15 data.frame, each with at 10 rows. Hopefully this could help you with what you are trying to do with your data-set.

```
seq.int <- seq(0, nrow(iris), 10)
seq.gp <- cut(1:nrow(iris), breaks=seq.int, include.lowest=TRUE)

iris_list <- split(iris, seq.gp)
```

You can then manipulate each data.frame within the list using list-friendly loops or lapply. Afterwhich, each data.frame can then be written out as separate csv as so:

```
names(iris_list) <- paste0("test1_", sprintf("%02d", 1:length(iris_list)))
lapply(names(iris_list), function(x) write.csv(iris_list[[x]], paste0(x, ".csv")))
```